# Inclusions over tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M, M'$ be algebras (I work with bounded linear operators, but I don't think this is a necessary detail here), and also let $M \cong M_1 \otimes M_2$ and $M' \cong M_1' \otimes M_2'$. If $M_1 \subset M_1'$ and $M_2 \subset M_2'$, does it immediately follow that $M \subset M'$? Is there a counter-example somewhere?

Comment: If $\iota_{1/2}:M_{1/2}\to M_{1/2}'$ are the natural inclusions, then $\iota:M_1\otimes M_2\to M_1'\otimes M_2',~a\otimes b\mapsto \iota_1(a)\otimes \iota_2(b)$ should be a natural inclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true over a field but not over a more general commutative ring $k$. Since we only consider tensor products this is really a question about modules. If $M$ is a $k$-module, the tensor product $M \otimes_k (-)$ preserves injections iff $M$ is [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module), and similarly for the tensor product $(-) \otimes_k M$. Applying this fact twice gives the desired result if either $M_2$ and $M_1'$ are both flat, or $M_1$ and $M_2'$ are both flat; this is automatic if $k$ is a field, since then every $k$-module is flat.

Since you say you're working with bounded linear operators I assume you're working over $k = \mathbb{C}$ or maybe $k = \mathbb{R}$ so everything is fine if you're working with the ordinary tensor product. But with bounded linear operators you may be working with some completed tensor product and then things might depend delicately on which completed tensor product you're using (I don't know either way).